# Overriding the theme attribute inside of a style?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have a project where I defined all the styles in the theme (Button style, Checkbox Style, EditText style and so on) This way I don't need to apply any style or theme in the layouts where I use those views, because they are applied automatically by my AppTheme.

Now I encountered a problem. I wanted to define the Switch style inside the theme but it should use another color for the colorControlActivated and colorControlHighlight. By default it uses the colorPrimary which I defined in the theme, but what if I want to change that.

The problem can be fixed easy with a theme overlay or a style where I override the needed attributes that I mentioned above and apply that style/theme everywhere where I use the Swtch view. But I want to know if I can avoid that and define a default style for my Switch views inside the same theme where the colorControlActivated and colorControlHighlight are already defined.

I tried several things but this looked like the one that actually might work but it does not:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/white</item>


    <item name="switchStyle">@style/SwitchStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.GreenControlOverlay">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

the SwitchStyle looks like this

```
<style name="SwitchStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/AppTheme.GreenControlOverlay</item>
</style>
```

I dont know why this is not working because if I set the android:theme inside my AppTheme directly it does override the colorControl attributes, but if you override it  from a style it does not work. If I apply this GreenControlOverlay on the Switch view inside of my layout it also works.

Is it even possible to do this?

If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. I hope I explained my problem well.

Comment: Why do you avoid solution with creating new theme which will override your AppTheme and apply it for your activity?

Comment: Overriding the activity theme is fine, but then everything will be green where there is controlBackgrund involved, and I just want to have that on the Switch view. For example if I would override the activity theme then the buttons would have a green ripple effect.